# Unable to 'vagrant ssh' after successful provisioning

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

Using vagrant 1.2.7 with virtualbox 4.2.16 on OS X 10.8.4

```
sudo vagrant up

Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Creating shared folders metadata...
[default] Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
[default] Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
[default] Forwarding ports...
[default] -- 22 => 2222 (adapter 1)
[default] Running 'pre-boot' VM customizations...
[default] Booting VM...
[default] Waiting for VM to boot. This can take a few minutes.
[default] VM booted and ready for use!
[default] Mounting shared folders...
[default] -- /vagrant

vagrant ssh

VM must be created before running this command. Run `vagrant up` first.
```

But, as shown above it booted and ready for use.

I enabled 'gui' mode, and the vb is running but unable to ssh from host.

I noticed that the vb adapter is 'NAT'ing'. Should I switch to 'bridge'?. Also, when running :

#VBoxManage list runningvms

I get nothing, like there were no vbs running, but it is.

Any help greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: see this http://superuser.com/questions/342473/vagrant-ssh-fails-with-virtualbox

Comment: Thanks, but not related. I am able to boot, and seems to be getting a good ip. The host doesn't seem to see it running tough

Comment: If `VBoxManage list runningvms` shows nothing then the VM is not running. NAT is fine, as long as you don't have 2 vagrant vms (NAT) running at the same time. Check your `Vagrantfile`.

Comment: Terry, even though I get no results from 'runningvms', I know it is running because in gui mode I can log in, restart networking, etc..

Comment: Yep, do a `ps -ef | grep -i virtualbox` and `vagrant status` to confirm. Also, what happens if you do `ssh -p 2222 vagrant@localhost`?

Comment: It might be issue with the box, see this askubuntu.com/questions/324574/cannot-ssh-into-new-vagrant-install-of-13-04

Answer (score 4):

Came across this question while trying to find a solution to my own problem.  It appears that vagrant is tied to the user it is launched under.  In your code above, you use `sudo vagrant up` which runs vagrant as root.  You're then running `vagrant ssh` as another lower level user, so vagrant can't see a running vm.  Either use sudo for both or neither.

Answer (score 0):

Mine was a GIT issue. I did:

```
$ vagrant up

// some time later 
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "in progress"
$ git checkout develop  

// some time later 

$ vagrant ssh
```

and got

> VM must be running to open SSH connection. Run `vagrant up`
>   to start the virtual machine.

After a few minutes of vigorous head scratching, I realized that the commit and checkout had effectively removed the vagrant cache file from the directory.

`$ git checkout original-branch` fixed my issue. It may be obvious to others, but it took me a minute to realize in the heat of the moment.